# Update UICollectionViewCell Before Scroll?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a working `UICollectionViewCell` in `UITableViewCell`. I'm using [HWViewPager](https://github.com/vowed21/HWViewPager), so the `collectionview` cell moves from left to right. Unfortunately, the data is not updated until the user scrolls to the left or to the right. The content that fills up the cell is fetched from `json`, so I figure that has something to do but I'm not sure what. I load everything in **awakeFromNib**.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
]    videoArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self getDisco];


}
```

with getDisco being a void function.

```
- (void)getDisco
{

   AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager GET:url parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {



        videoArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[responseObject valueForKey:@"releases"]];


       // NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];



}
```

Now, where the problem is.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    if (indexPath.item < [videoArray count]){
        DiscoCell * cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CollectionCell2" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSDictionary *shot = [videoArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        cell.label2.text = [shot objectForKey:@"title"];
        return cell;
        return nil;
    }else{

        DiscoCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CollectionCell2" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.label2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %d", indexPath.row];

        return cell;
    }


}
```

Without the if/else statements, the `viewcontroller` crashed completely. With it, nothing updates till the user scrolls. My question is how do I get it all to pre-load, without crashing, for the user? Please keep `UICollectionViewCell` is in a `tableviewcell`.

Comment: After http operation done, reload the `UICollectionView`.

Comment: HI There i'm also using HWView pager as a sub view in an application from super view when i call this HWViewpager reload data its reloading the whole view data. Plz help if you have some idea about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reload collectionView after finished the request:

```
- (void)getDisco
{

   AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager GET:@"http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/release/?query=arid:e0140a67-e4d1-4f13-8a01-364355bee46e%20AND%20primarytype:single&fmt=json&limit=100" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {



        videoArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[responseObject valueForKey:@"releases"]];


       // NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
       [collectionView reloadData];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];



}
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. Thank you so much!

Comment: HI There i'm also using HWView pager as a sub view in an application from super view when i call this HWViewpager reload data its reloading the whole view data. Plz help if you have some idea about it.

Comment: Sorry, maybe you should create a question. Thank you. @WaqarAhmed